# UserAccounts_RowEditing/Updating is not working properly

Tags: asp.net, gridview

Alright, so I have a Gridview and added RowEditing and RowUpdating to it, but it won't really edit something.. This is my code for both:

```
protected void UserAccounts_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
     UserAccounts.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
     BindUserAccounts();
}
protected void UserAccounts_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
     int index = UserAccounts.EditIndex;
     GridViewRow row = UserAccounts.Rows[e.RowIndex];
     username = UserAccounts.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Text;
     email = ((TextBox)row.Cells[2].Controls[0]).Text;
     MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser(username);
     if (user != null)
     {
         user.Email = email;
         Membership.UpdateUser(user);
         ActionStatus.Text = string.Format("User {0} details have been successfully updated!", username);
     }
     UserAccounts.EditIndex = -1;
     BindUserAccounts();
}
```

What am I doing wrong in here?

EDIT: This is my BindUserAccounts:

```
private void BindUserAccounts()
{
     int totalRecords;
     UserAccounts.DataSource = Membership.FindUsersByName(this.UsernameToMatch + "%", this.PageIndex, this.PageSize, out totalRecords);
     UserAccounts.DataBind();

     bool visitingFirstPage = (this.PageIndex == 0);
     lnkFirst.Enabled = !visitingFirstPage;
     lnkPrev.Enabled = !visitingFirstPage;

     int lastPageIndex = (totalRecords - 1) / this.PageSize;
     bool visitingLastPage = (this.PageIndex >= lastPageIndex);
     lnkNext.Enabled = !visitingLastPage;
     lnkLast.Enabled = !visitingLastPage;
}
```

Comment: Changes what you make, are they reflecting in database?

Comment: The database is not changing too. Also, the delete button is working properly so its not a database error..

Comment: So, binding is having issue. (`BindUserAccounts();`)

Comment: Edited my question with BindUserAccounts()

Comment: I found no issue in your coding, except what returning from `Membership.FindUsersByName`. Try debugging inside it.

Comment: Somehow it works now after editing the GridView and set "UserName", "IsApproved", "IsLockedOut" and "IsOnline" to ReadOnly="true"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think the should be like this

```
 protected void update_click_foredu(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{

    Label edui = (Label)edugrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("label");
    TextBox unitxt = (TextBox)edugrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtuni");





    if (unitxt != null && costxt != null && startdatetxt != null && enddatetxt != null)
    {
        using (Entities1 context = new Entities1())
        {
            string eduID =  edui.Text;
            model obj = context.entitytabel.First(x =>  x.ID == eduID);
            obj.Univ_Name = unitxt.Text;

            context.SaveChanges();
            lblMessage.Text = "Saved successfully.";
            edugrid.EditIndex = -1;

            bindgrid();

        }
    }
}
```

here im using EF  like this you can find the control of the text box and save it in gridview

hope this helps you

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand anything from it :D

Answer (score 0):

Somehow it works now after editing the GridView and set "UserName", "IsApproved", "IsLockedOut" and "IsOnline" to ReadOnly="true"